# Print labels of the nearest neighbours from scikit KNeighborsClassifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I am using KNeighborsClassifier algorithm to train my data as below:

```python
knn_clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, 
algorithm="ball_tree", weights='distance')
```

I got the nearest 3 neighbours of the data from:

```python
closest_distances = knn_clf.kneighbors(faces_encodings, n_neighbors=3)
print(closest_distances) #printouts: (array([[0.1123 , 0.29189484, 0.312]]
```

I want to link the distances of these 3 nearest neighbours with the labels. Any ideas ?

My training data: X:[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5] y:[one, two, three, four, five]. If i give predict(0.2), how can i link the labels of the found distances as two, three, four ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not assign `knn_clf.kneighbors` to a single variable `closest_distances`, as you do; `kneighbors` method [returns **two** variables](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.kneighbors):

> **Returns:**
>
> **dist** : array
>
> Array representing the lengths to points, only present if return_distance=True
>
> **ind** : array
>
> Indices of the nearest points in the population matrix.

So, you should give

```python
closest_distances, indices = knn_clf.kneighbors(faces_encodings, n_neighbors=3)
```

and the `indices` variable will contain the required indices.

Comment: Thank you :) I didnot see it returns index too